# Как в одну форму вставить 2 действия

Tags: c#, .net, razor

Есть одна форма регистрации с двумя типами клиентов, юридическое и физическое лицо.Вопрос в том,как их разграничить.Пока есть такой код, где работает отправка 1 формы 
C#

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Email,EmailPersо...")] CreateClientCommand command)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var creat = Mediator.Send(new CreateClientCommand()
            {
                Email = command.Email,
                Type = command.Type,
                EmailPerso = command.EmailPerso,
                Country = command.Country,
                Adress = command.Adress,
            }).Result;
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(command);
    }
```

HTML

```
<form asp-action="Create">
 ...
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1"><button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Create"> VALIDER</button></div>
</form>
```

Проблема в том,как это лучше сделать в одной форме?

Comment: Если у вас 2 разных действия, то, наверное, это должны быть 2 разные формы.

Comment: Либо добавьте radio button или checkbox, по которому Вы будете определять к какому типу (CreateLegalEntity, CreatePerson) относится создаваемый объект и приводите его к нужному типу.